# Gabor Filter (Wavelet) implementation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, signal-processing, wavelet

I'm trying to create Gabor filters with the following code :

```
function [g] = generate_gabor_filter(sigma, phi, theta)

% filter size : 
w = 39; h = 39;

x0 = ((w+1)/2); y0 =((h+1)/2);

for x=1:w
    for y=1:h
        xp = (x-x0) * cos(theta) + (y-y0) * sin(theta);
        yp = (x-x0) * -sin(theta) + (y-y0) * cos(theta);
        g(x,y) = exp( -pi * sigma^2 * (xp^2+yp^2))  *   exp(j*(2*pi*phi*(x+y)));
    end
end

end
```

When I call this with the following parameters :

```
phi_values = [pi/2 , pi/4 , pi/8];
theta_values = pi/6 * [0:5];
sigma = 0.1; % why ?

for scale = 1:3
   for orientation = 1:6
       phi = phi_values(scale); theta = theta_values(orientation);
       gfb{scale,orientation} = generate_gabor_filter(sigma , phi , theta);
   end
end
```

The result is shown below. I'm also sending the image of only filter (1,5) , to make the black-white pixel pattern more visible.

[image]
 [image: Filter (1,5) - zoomed]

It resembles the "transparency layer" of Photoshop, but I have never seen this in MATLAB before. Is my code actually creating this black-white pattern?

And there is obviously something wrong in my code since the outputs are all oriented with the same angle (`pi/4` I think).

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Are you sure you're implementing the Gabor filters right?  The definition that I know of is different than how you have coded it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_filter#Definition - Also check the example MATLAB script in the Wikipedia article I linked to above that calculates the filter.